# Задача по языку C

Tags: c

Всем здравствуйте, решаю такую задачу: Заданы два массива по 5 целых чисел в каждом. Найти наименьшее среди чисел первого массива, которое не входит во второй массив (считая, что хотя бы одно такое число есть).

Код для такой задачки я уже написал, но столкнулся с пониманием "Найти наименьшее среди чисел первого массива, которое не входит во второй массив (считая, что хотя бы одно такое число есть).". То есть по моей логике, если ввод первого массива к примеру:
0 1 2 3 4
ввод второго массива:
0 2 3 4 5
То наименьшим числом, исходя из условия задачи будет число 1, т.к. оно не входит во второй массив. Это так? Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int arr1[5]; //инициализируем массивы
    int arr2[5];
    printf("Введите числа первого массива\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int element;
        scanf_s("%d", &element); // ввод чисел массива 1
        arr1[i] = element;
    }
    printf("Введите числа второго массива\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int element;
        scanf_s("%d", &element); // ввод чисел массива 2
        arr2[i] = element;
    }
    int min1 = arr1[0];
    int min2 = arr2[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // алгоритм поиска минимального числа массива 1
    {
        if (min1 > arr1[i])
        {

            min1 = arr1[i];
        }
        if (min2 > arr2[i])
        {
            min2 = arr2[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Ну с кодом предельно понятно, но вот, как сделать эту проверку, если ввод первого массива
0 1 2 3 4
а второго
0 2 3 4 5
то как убрать этот ноль несчастный, совсем не понимаю, много чего перепробовал, голова уже болит.
Помогите пожалуйста!!

Comment: Вам надо просто перебирать все числа первого массива и искать их во втором. Если не нашли там, то смотрите, если оно меньше текущего минимума, то меняете текущий минимум. В конце вы получите искомое число.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вы полагаетесь на отсортированность массивов,но я не вижу этого в условии...

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо найти первое то поступите просто

1. отсортируйте первый массив (через qsort)
2. итерируетесь по массиву и если нашли отсутсвие элемента в нем это и есть ваш элемент

пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARR_SIZE 5

int comp(const void *i, const void *j)
{
    return *(int *)i - *(int *)j;
}

int exist(int val, int *arr, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] == val)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[ARR_SIZE] = {2, 3, 0, 0, 0};
    int arr2[ARR_SIZE] = {1, 2, 0, 0, 0};
    qsort(arr1, ARR_SIZE, sizeof(int), (int (*)(const void *, const void *))comp);
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        if (!exist(arr1[i], arr2, ARR_SIZE))
        {
            ret = arr1[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", ret);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: При `arr1 = {2, 3, 0, 0, 0}; arr2 = {1, 2, 0, 0, 0};` работает неверно.

Comment: @wololo спасибо за замечание - поправил ответ!